# Building a Collection from a type name (string)

Tags: c++

Is there any way to build a template class (I specifically need a `std::map`, but question is more general) from a string description?

I need to read a config file (XML, if it matters) and build a `std::map<std::string, unique_ptr<type>>` where `type` is read from the config file and is supposed to be a scalar type (`int32_t`/`int64_t`/`float`/`double`/etc.).

Actually my problem is a bit more complex because I need to instantiate a `template class` wrapping the `std::map` and correctly handling its content, but my problem is actually getting a `typename` from a string.

I need the reverse of `typeid(typename)::name()`.

Comment: There is no way to do this in C++ that isn't essentially some hard coded list of names and associated types. C++ does not have reflection.

Comment: With an explicit list of types (your `int32_t`/`int64_t`/`float`/`double`/etc.) this is not hard to do, The reverse of `typeid(typename)::name()`, however, cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

Types must be known at compile time. You cannot specialize a template at runtime. If you design the code well, you need to implement "switching" on the type strings only a single time.

If you're able to keep the types out of the function signature of the type containing the map, you may not even need this amount of flexibility. (Otherwise `std::variant<WrapperType<int32_t>, WrapperType<int64_t>, ...>` may also be an option you could use.)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

/**
 * abstract interface providing function signatures
 */
struct WrapperBase
{
    virtual ~WrapperBase() = default;

    virtual void ReadEntry(std::string&& str, std::istream& s) = 0;
    virtual void Display(std::ostream& s) = 0;
};

/**
 * Implementations of WrapperBase
 */
template<class T>
struct Wrapper : WrapperBase
{
    std::map<std::string, T> m_map;

    void ReadEntry(std::string&& str, std::istream& s) override
    {
        T value;
        s >> value;
        if (s)
        {
            m_map.emplace(std::move(str), value);
        }
    }

    void Display(std::ostream& s) override
    {
        for (auto& [key, value] : m_map)
        {
            s << key << " => " << value << '\n';
        }
    }

};

/**
 * a bit of an overkill here, but just here to demonstrate a function 
 * providing more flexibility than simply calling
 * std::make_unique<Wrapper<SomeType>> based on the typeName
 */
template<template<class> class T, class...Args>
decltype(auto) DoForType(std::string_view typeName, Args&&...args)
{
    if (typeName == "int32_t")
    {
        return T<int32_t>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    else if (typeName == "int64_t")
    {
        return T<int64_t>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    else if (typeName == "float")
    {
        return T<float>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    else if (typeName == "double")
    {
        return T<double>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("unknown typeName ").append(typeName));
    }
}

/**
 * Helper class for creating the appropriate wrapper type with DoForType
 */
template<class T>
struct WrapperCreator
{
    std::unique_ptr<WrapperBase> operator()()
    {
        return std::make_unique<Wrapper<T>>();
    }
};

void Test(std::string&& str)
{
    std::istringstream s(std::move(str));

    std::string type;
    s >> type;

    std::cout << "type = " << type << '\n';

    auto wrapper = DoForType<WrapperCreator>(type);


    while (s)
    {
        std::string key;
        s >> key;
        if (s)
        {
            wrapper->ReadEntry(std::move(key), s);
        }
    }

    wrapper->Display(std::cout);
}

int main()
{
    Test("int32_t foo 1 bar 2");
    Test("double foo 2.5 bar 99.99");
}
```

Comment: I suspect this could be done with a bit less code with `std::variant`